# performance testing tool with record &use function

Tags: performance

I am looking for performance tool which should have record and use function, I looked into jmeter though. Is there any other tool? which has record option too

I understand manual editing will be there even we record and playback,but at least I don't need to give URL manually. I have used jmeter, manage engine Qengine too.

I also tried to convert my selenium scripts to jmeter performance testing ,but I am not able to get every URL's request /response.

requirements :

1. http/https
2. record and playback - I can write scripts
3. option to substitute parameter from response etc. (which is dynamic)

Answer (score 0):

You may try [Silk performer](http://www.borland.com/us/products/silk/silkperformer/) or [HP Load Runner](https://h10078.www1.hp.com/cda/hpms/display/main/hpms_content.jsp?zn=bto&cp=1-11-126-17%5E8_4000_100). But both the tools are expensive to buy. Other opensource tools include [Grinder](http://grinder.sourceforge.net/)